# Can I run a mobile app in development disconnected from the dev computer?

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a mobile application which uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), am considering Cordova as the platform to use and would like to be able to load the test application onto a mobile device, disconnect it from the development computer and bring it into "the field" to test.  The BLE devices are scattered around a huge building.

Testing will be done on both Android and IOS devices.

Is this possible using Cordova?

Thanks in advance,
Gee

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for Cordova and a plugin like [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central)